# Probability of a tail event

Tags: probability, borel-cantelli-lemmas, distribution-tails

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables such that

$$P(X_n = 0 \text{  eventually}) = 1 $$

Does this imply that

$$P(\sum_{i=1}^nX_{n,i} = 0 \text{  eventually}) = 1 $$

where $X_{n,1},X_{n,2},...$ is i.i.d. and has the same distribution as $X_n$ for all $n$.

Do you agree or disagree with this result. Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: OP, I've seen that you have already asked six questions on this website without acknowledging any of the answers that people have given to you. On this website it is expected that if you are satisfied with an answer, you indicate your approval by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: @EvanAad I agree with you.

Comment: @EvanAad Sorry about that I did not know where the check mark is.

Comment: The other side of the coin is that, if you're not satisfied with any of the answers that have been provided, you should try to explain to the people who posted an answer - by posting a comment below their answers - why their answer is unsatisfactory (i.e. what part of the answer you find wrong/unclear/difficult to understand). Then the answerers have an opportunity to correct or modify their answer based on your notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implication is false. Here's a counterexample. Consider the standard probability space, $\left([0,1], \mathcal{B}, P=\lambda\right)$. For every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ define $A_n := \left[0, \frac{1}{n}\right]$. Then $A_1\supseteq A_2 \supseteq \cdots$ is a decreasing sequence of events, such that, for every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, $P(A_n) = \frac{1}{n}$. For every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ define the random variable $X_n := \mathbb{1}_{A_n}$. Then, on the one hand, $P\left(X_n = 0\text{ eventually}\right) = 1$. On the other hand, since, for every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, $X_n \sim \mathrm{Bin}\left(1, \frac{1}{n}\right)$, then, given i.i.d. random variables $X_{n, 1}, X_{n, 2}, \dots, X_{n, n}$ that are equally distributed like $X_n$, we have $S_n := X_{n, 1} + \cdots + X_{n, n} \sim \mathrm{Bin}\left(n, \frac{1}{n}\right)$, so that $P(S_n = 0) = \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\rightarrow e^{-1}$. We may assume, w.l.g., that the random variables $S_n$, $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, are independent. Then, since
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty P(S_n > 0) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right) = \infty,
$$
the Borel-Cantelli lemma yields that $P(S_n > 0\text{ infinitely often}) = 1$, so that $P\left(S_n = 0\text{ eventually}\right) = 0$.

Comment: I don't think this sum diverges.  We have $(1 - p_n)^n \ge 1 - np_n$, and so $\sum_n (1 - (1 - p_n)^n) \le \sum_n (1 - (1 - n p_n)) = \sum_n n p_n = \sum_n n 2^{-n}$, which converges.

Comment: @Shagnik: You're right. Thanks! I've corrected my argument. What do you think now?

Comment: This looks good to me.  Nice construction!

Comment: @Shagnik: Thanks!